# Making Rails application work with iPhone

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

At work we have an web application that was not built to support smartphones. Now, we have a need to offer a couple of simple features that can be accessed from a smartphone. My question is this: is it possible to detect a user-agent for a smartphone and serve different template files and/or layout for that agent?

We don't have the time/manpower to write an iPhone app, but if I can make the web version compatible with an iPhone resolution in a couple nights I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need iPhone-specific CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

I think following would help you

1) Make your layout mobile compatible with something like [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), Following is the [gem for rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)

2) Detect the request agent and server the pages accordingly, [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices)

3) This is a gem ([mobile_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu)) which will help you, but seems like this bit outdated

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There's mobvious which I use and like:

https://github.com/jistr/mobvious

You can then put device-type specific layouts under their own subdirectories when you want to override the other, for example views/mobile/users/index.html.erb

but a quick Google search shows many other options such as:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/